# use Skrollr fixd height working wrong

Tags: javascript

I use Skrollr.js to test parallax background.
example code
http://jsfiddle.net/r0g5ade7/

```
<div
        class="parallax-image-wrapper"
        data-anchor-target="#bacons + .gap"
        data-bottom-top="transform:translate3d(0px, 200%, 0px)"
        data-top-bottom="transform:translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px)"
        style="height:1500px;top:-1500px;">

        <div
            class="parallax-image"
            style="background-image:url(http://bmws010.ugear.tw/ImgAdmin/Diary/f1m.jpg);height:1500px;top:0;"
            data-anchor-target="#bacons + .gap"
            data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -80%, 0px);"
            data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 80%, 0px);"
        ></div>
```

the example has 3 images frame ,I try to change 2nd image frame height from 100% to 1500px ,but  the background working wrong.

if resize the window ,the frame working wrong.

this is my test code http://jsfiddle.net/r0g5ade7/3/

how I fix the problem.

Comment: what expected result?

Comment: In short,I want to set frame 1500px,not 100%